# psycopg2 - Insertion - tsrange & character varying types

Tags: python, datetime, insert, psycopg2

I have managed to get a connection from Python using the psycopg2 module, and I want to insert data to the "invigilation" table having the following four columns:

```
course_id = "651" # Character varying(6) 
date = "[2015-08-22 10:00:00,2015-08-22 12:00:00)" #tsrange 
room_id = "d2" #text 
duration = 150 #smallint
```

The date field is currently formatted as a string. I am aware of "[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)" module; however, when I search through the modules in PyCharm the closest to appear is "DateTime" from Zope Foundation..

When I try to insert the data as follows, I receive the error "ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "date".

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO invigilation (course_id date room_id duration)     
\VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s", (course_id, date, room_id, str(duration)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of columns after your `INSERT_INTO` needs to be comma-separated, but you have used spaces ([see reference](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert/)). After course_id, a comma is expected, but instead you have written 'date' which is why the syntax error is found at this location.

You're also missing a closing `)` at the end of your SQL statement.